# Как мне связать таблицу в rails с уже существующими таблицами

Tags: ruby-on-rails, плагин, redmine

Я пишу плагин на Rails для Redmine (дипломная работа).
Я хочу создать свою таблицу задач, у которой был бы свой id, при этом она содержала бы в себе некоторые необходимые мне данные из других таблиц, пытаюсь я это сделать через существующую таблицу задач issues. Мне нужен номер задачи, проект, юзер - которому назначена задача, трекер, статус, тема.

Я понимаю, что у меня неправильно, так как миграция проходит безуспешно. Как мне лучше подойти к решению этой проблемы?

**Моя модель**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  unlodable
  has_one :issue
  has_one :project, through: :issue
  has_one :traker, through: :issue
  has_one :assigned_to, through: :issue
  has_one :subject, through: :issue
  has_one :status, through: :issue

end
```

**Мой файл миграции**

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.integer :issue_id
      t.string :issue_project
      t.string :issue_assigned_to
      t.string :issue_status
      t.string :issue_subject
    end
  end
end
```

**Таблица issues в схеме Redmine**

```
create_table "issues", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "tracker_id", null: false
    t.integer "project_id", null: false
    t.string "subject", default: "", null: false
    t.text "description", limit: 4294967295
    t.date "due_date"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "status_id", null: false
    t.integer "assigned_to_id"
    t.integer "priority_id", null: false
    t.integer "fixed_version_id"
    t.integer "author_id", null: false
    t.integer "lock_version", default: 0, null: false
    t.timestamp "created_on"
    t.timestamp "updated_on"
    t.date "start_date"
    t.integer "done_ratio", default: 0, null: false
    t.float "estimated_hours"
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.integer "root_id"
    t.integer "lft"
    t.integer "rgt"
    t.boolean "is_private", default: false, null: false
    t.datetime "closed_on"
    t.index ["assigned_to_id"], name: "index_issues_on_assigned_to_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_issues_on_author_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_issues_on_category_id"
    t.index ["created_on"], name: "index_issues_on_created_on"
    t.index ["fixed_version_id"], name: "index_issues_on_fixed_version_id"
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_issues_on_parent_id"
    t.index ["priority_id"], name: "index_issues_on_priority_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "issues_project_id"
    t.index ["root_id", "lft", "rgt"], name: "index_issues_on_root_id_and_lft_and_rgt"
    t.index ["status_id"], name: "index_issues_on_status_id"
    t.index ["tracker_id"], name: "index_issues_on_tracker_id"
  end
```

**Последнее изменение в файле миграции**

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  create_join_table :tasks, :issues, :projects, :trackers, :status do |t|
    t.integer :issue_id
    t.string :project_name
    t.string :issue_assigned_to_id
    t.string :traker_name
    t.string :status_name
    t.string :issue_subject
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Таблица `tasks` совершенно правильно хранит `issue_id`. Это говорит о том, что связь должна быть `belongs_to :issue`, а не `has_one`. Все остальные поля в `tasks` не нужны, эти данные вы можете получить через связи

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.integer :issue_id
    end
  end
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  unlodable
  belongs_to :issue
  has_one :project, through: :issue
  has_one :traker, through: :issue
  has_one :assigned_to, through: :issue
  has_one :subject, through: :issue
  has_one :status, through: :issue

end
```

Comment: Спасибо. Значит далее уже файл миграции нужно исправлять?

Comment: Да, конечно, всё же через миграции

Comment: Я не уверен как правильно сделать. Уверен, что в итоге получилось неверно, но не могу предположить как лучше. Я в вопросе добавил последние изменения. Можно ли как-то так сделать?
Я совершенный новичок в рельсах, поэтому, наверно, вопросы глупые..

Comment: Обновила ответ. Кажется, вам стоит почитать про ассоциации http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations

Comment: Да, я читал этот источник и сейчас тоже. Не сразу всё доходит. У меня есть последний вопрос, не совсем по теме. Могу ли я как-то в своём контроллере, у меня tasks, обратиться к какой-либо таблице БД?

Comment: Обычно к таблицам через модели обращаются. Да, в контроллере можно к любой модели обратиться

Comment: Спасибо. А где почитать обо всём этом не подскажите? Именно о том, как через модель к таблице обратиться.

Comment: Вы меня простите за бестактность, но у меня ощущение, что вам очень надо прочитать вот это http://rusrails.ru/, первые 4 главы. Если можете на инглише, то лучше оригинал https://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Я понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду и согласен с вами. У меня проблема не просто с пониманием рельс, а с тем что у меня задача интеграции в сложную для меня систему. И я не понимаю как можно и как нельзя, при том что постоянно ломается приложение, через которое работает Redmine у меня. После того как я сделал предложенные вами действия это снова случилось. Я очень вам благодарен за уделённое вами мне время. Я очень ценю это, так как мне в принципе не у кого спросить совета.

Comment: Я с редмайном никогда не работала, поэтому по нему ничего посоветовать не могу, к сожалению. Мне просто странно, что вы решаете задачу, которая явно сложнее, чем вам по силам - слишком много всего нужно изучить для её решения

Comment: Я в общем почитал источник, которым вы поделились в последний раз. Там немного не так как вы сказали, но в итоге я смог пока одну из поставленных задач решить. Я вам очень благодарен, вы мой бог!) По сути просто в миграции в создании таблицы должна быть эта строчка `t.belongs_to :issues`